# PHP Redirect Not Working (Inside if statement)

Tags: php, html, redirect, http-headers

The following code compares the current page to the site root and redirects if different.

This work fine locally but not on the server.

```
<?php

ob_start();

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/includes.php');

if (SITE_FULL_URL !== SITE_URL . '/') {

    redirect(SITE_URL);

} else {

    /* Page Switcher */
    switch ($urlarray[0]) {
        case '':
            require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mod/home/index.php');
            break;
        default:
            require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mod/404/index.php');
            break;
    }

}

ob_end_flush();
```

As soon as the redirect function is placed inside an if statement it stops working.

The redirect function is as follows:

```
function redirect($url) {
    if(!headers_sent()) {
        //If headers not sent yet... then do php redirect
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    } else {
        //If headers are sent... do javascript redirect... if javascript disabled, do html redirect.
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide value of SITE_FULL_URL and SITE_URL constants

Comment: place `die` after the function.